# Dbus Bluez Indicate Notification

Tags: dbus, bluez

In Dbus the interface for org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1 has an interface StartNotify().  This works fine with a callback defined.  How do I enable notify with **indicate**?

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is `notify` or `indicate` that the `StartNotify()` function uses is defined by the characteristic it is operating on.

As an example, using `bluetoothctl` to look at two characteristics on a BBC micro:bit you can see that one supports `notify` and one supports `indicate`. You would use `StartNotify()` on both.

```
[bluetooth]# connect E1:4B:6C:22:56:F0 
Attempting to connect to E1:4B:6C:22:56:F0
[CHG] Device E1:4B:6C:22:56:F0 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device E1:4B:6C:22:56:F0 ServicesResolved: yes
[BBC micro:bit [toveg]]# gatt.attribute-info e95d9250-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8
Characteristic - Vendor specific
        UUID: e95d9250-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8
        Service: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E1_4B_6C_22_56_F0/service003c
        Notifying: no
        Flags: read
        Flags: notify
[BBC micro:bit [toveg]]# gatt.attribute-info 6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e
Characteristic - Nordic UART TX
        UUID: 6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e
        Service: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E1_4B_6C_22_56_F0/service0028
        Notifying: no
        Flags: indicate
```

Comment: I have issue where one device (ble peripheral) has flags [write, notify, indicate] and with one write command,  StartNotify() will only return one set of value, on Android "NRF Connect app", I am getting 4 sets of value.

Comment: I try to read the value of the Descriptor it returns 0x3, if I am not mistaken it is notify + indicate is enabled which is not normal but acceptable options.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a good question for the BlueZ slack channel https://www.bluez.org/contact/